# Doctrine2 Query builder problem with like

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I'm using this for in my doctrine2 query but it won't work

```
  $obj_query_builder->select('p')
   ->from('General\Domain\Product', 'p')
   ->where('p.cach_all_stop_words LIKE ?', '%avond%');
```

It must be this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `cach_all_stop_words` LIKE '%avond%'
```

But there is an error in my query I think

Answer (score 14):

The QueryBuilder syntax in Doctrine 2 which is defined in http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html is slightly different than the one you used in your query.

Can you try this query:

```
$obj_query_builder->add('select', 'p')
  ->add('from', 'General\Domain\Product p')
  ->add('where', 'p.cach_all_stop_words LIKE ?1')
  ->setParameter(1, '%avond%')
```

You can also see some other examples in the link I posted above.

EDIT: I saw below in the page in "Helper methods" that your syntax should also work. Try the query I wrote above.

Answer (score 3):

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb -> select('p')
    ->from('General\Domain\Product' , 'p')
    ->where($qb->expr()->like('p.cach_all_stop_words', $qb->expr()->literal('%avond%')));

$query = $qb->getQuery();
```